# Variable might not be initialized

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure whats wrong with my code. When I compile it says variable `checkfee` might not have been initialized.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BankCharge  {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int check, basefee;
        String temp;
        double checkfee; 
        double totalfee;
        basefee = 10;
        totalfee = checkfee + basefee;


        temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of checks");
        check = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        if (check < 20) {
            checkfee = .10 * check;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your amount for the month is " + totalfee);
        }
        if (check >= 20 && check <= 39) {
            checkfee = .08 * check;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your amount for the month is " + totalfee);
        }
        if (check >= 40 && check <= 59) {
            checkfee = .06 * check;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your amount for the month is " + totalfee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are finding totalfee without initialising checkfee

Comment: totalfee = checkfee + basefee;

Answer (score 1):

**Because the initialization of `checkfee` variable is always done in conditional stament (`if`), it's not guaranteed to be initialized.**

Answer (score 0):

This warning is not important. You can write `double checkfee=0;` to remove it. What do you do if check >60 ??

Comment: i disagree that *it's not important*. although your suggestion will make this warning disappear